# How to calculate the derivative of a function in respect to its path

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Let $f :\mathbb R^2 → \mathbb R^3$ be defined by $f (u, v) = (u, v, u\sin(uv))$ . Let $ g(t)$ be a path with $g(0) = (1,π)$ and $g'(0) = (1,2)$. What is the velocity of the path $f ◦ g $ at $t = 0$?

I have no idea how to start or solve this problem. I know that I need to take the derivative to find the velocity. But I don't know how to do it when path's are involved. Please help.

Comment: Try the chain rule.

Comment: @TedShifrin Chain rule with what ? how can i do a chain rule with a path ?

Comment: You have a composition $f\circ g$, so it is a good candidate for the Chain Rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(t)=(x(t), y(t))$, then $g(0)=(x(0), y(0))=(1, \pi)$ and $g'(0)=(x'(0), y'(0))=(1, 2)$.

Sub. $(u,v)=(x(t), y(t))$ in to $f(u,v)$:

$$
\begin{aligned}~
[f\circ g](t) &= f(x(t),y(t))\\
&= (x,y, x\sin(xy))\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Differentiate w.r.t. $t$:

$$
\begin{aligned}~
[f\circ g]'(t)&= (x',y',x'\sin(xy)+x\cos(xy)(x'y+xy'))\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Sub. $t=0$:
$$
\begin{aligned}~
[f\circ g]'(0)&= (1, 2, 1\sin(\pi)+1\cos(\pi)(1\cdot\pi+1\cdot2))\\
&= (1, 2, -(\pi+2))
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2):

> But I don't know how to do it when path's are involved.

The Chain Rule for Jacobian matrices is this:  $\mathsf J[f\circ g](t)=\mathsf J[f](g(t))~\mathsf J[g](t)$

$\qquad\qquad\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d [f\circ g]}{\mathrm d t}(t)&=\left.\dfrac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial [u,v]}\right\rvert_{[u,v]^\top=g(t)}\cdot \dfrac{\mathrm d g(t)}{\mathrm d t}\\[1ex]&=\left.{\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial f_1(u,v)}{\partial u}&\dfrac{\partial f_1(u,v)}{\partial v}\\\dfrac{\partial f_2(u,v)}{\partial u}&\dfrac{\partial f_2(u,v)}{\partial v}\\\dfrac{\partial f_3(u,v)}{\partial u}&\dfrac{\partial f_3(u,v)}{\partial v}\end{bmatrix}\\}\right\vert_{\raise{2ex}{\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}=g(t)}} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}u'(t)\\v'(t)\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$